# Push server with web socket

Tags: android, websocket, push-notification

I'm building a simple push server that comunicate with other client throught web socket.

Now I want use a push notification with an Android application. I want to know if it is possible to implement a push notification with web socket in Android, if the Android SO, not close the connection to save battery level, cpu etc.

Then it is possible to implement this system in Android or there is other method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need the user to whitelist your app from battery saving optimizations.  You cannot do this programmatically.  Really you're going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to make this work, you're better off using an existing push messaging solution.

Comment: ok, what is the messagging solution existing ? Can we write me a list of it ?

Comment: @bircastri : Firebase Cloud Messaging is an "existing push messaging solution" referred to.